# JSP EL/Apache Tiles --- return object has composite key

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-roo

I have identified a problem using Spring MVC/Apache Tiles.

update.jspx presents an update form for current entity(Position.java) which has a composite key:

```
@RooJpaActiveRecord(persistenceUnit = "theUnit", transactionManager = "theManager", table = "theTable", identifierType = PositionPK.class)
Class Position{
    //User user;
    //Role role;
    //other fields....
}
```

It is an old legacy class using `User` and `Role` as composite key(meaning it is not a good design but we have to live with it). So I have another composite key class using @RooIdentifier

```
@RooIdentifier
Class PositionPK extends Serializable {
    User user;
    Role role;
    //override equals and hashCode blahblah...
}
```

The problem is, on update.jspx page, where I give a field to update `User` of the position, the form return no exceptions but return the `User` as `null`.

Then I try to add the user field back to Position class(not good design as well but for debugging purpose, so User exist both in entity class and PK class), now the application throw me an exception:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception
```

Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception

I dig about the exception it seems the entity class may missing getter/setter or id. As the getters/setters are all managed by Roo so it shouldn't be an issue, so I ponder the problem is the compatibility with how Spring MVC translates the primary key class to front end jsp view and vise versa.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the annotation for generating the getters and setters automatically in the code samples you have provided.

Since you have mentioned that Roo would manage getters and setters, could you try adding `@RooJavaBean` annotation to your primary key class?

Comment: Thank you. Yes those classes are annotated as at RooJavaBean but you are right most of that exception is caused by lack of setter/getters to the entity.

Comment: I have identified the problem is that some of the fields of the composite key class `PositionPK` are not well presented in the view page (I use position.user.id instead of position.id.user.id) so get the exception. I guess that is something need to take into consideration when using composite key class as there might two way to access the member field.